# Retreiving data from r-plotly generated html

Tags: javascript, html, dataset, r-plotly

I am working as an hydrogeologist and I was recently stolen my computer and I lost some data. I almost got it all back. Part of the data is definitely lost, but I've got it as an interactive graph in an html page. This page was generated using `plotly` package from Rstudio. It's interactive so I bet that the data is somewhere in the html code. Problem is, I don't know how to access to this data from the html only and could not get the solution from the internet.

Does anyone know **how to retreive data from a dynamic plot in an html graph**? My html page can be downloaded from [here](http://grosfi.ch/8KBa6tjmm7EUy).

Regards,

Liz

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I don't think many people on this site or going to download a random, large, file but you might be able to get assistance describing what you've attempted to do. It sounds likely your data *is* contained in the html or associated files. Is this download you've linked to a single file? or a zip of multiple files?